# Replace each tag p by tag li and around group li by tag ul

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

Here html :

```
<section class="category">
        <p><a href="product-list.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sed diam</a></p>
        <p><a href="product-list.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sed diam</a></p>
        <p><a href="product-list.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sed diam</a></p>
        <p><a href="product-list.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sed diam</a></p>
      <section class="clear"></section>
    </section>
```

How to replace tag p --> li and wrap group li by tag ul . I need it to be :

```
   <section class="category">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="product-list.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sed diam</a></li>
        <li><a href="product-list.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sed diam</a></li>
        <li><a href="product-list.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sed diam</a></li>
        <li><a href="product-list.html" >Lorem ipsum dolor sed diam</a></li>
      </ul>
      <section class="clear"></section>
</section>
```

Comment: Tip: There's no need for a clear-element (`section.clear`), just use one of the simple clearfix-solutions (`overflow: hidden;` on the parent is enough). Also, if you insist on using an html element to clear your floats, why would you use the semantic `section` element? `section` isn't here to _replace_ `div`, it's here to provide meaning to some of the things we used div for in the past. In the case of a clearing element, however, `section` is not the right fit, `div` is.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a combination of

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

and

http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/

```
$(".category p").wrapAll("<ul>").replaceWith(function() {
    return $("<li></li>").append($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.category').each(function(){
    var c = jQuery(this);
    var ul = jQuery('<ul/>');
    c.find('p').each(function(){
        var p = jQuery(this);
        ul.append(jQuery('<li/>').append(p.children()));
    }).remove();
    c.prepend(ul);        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery do this

```
    $("p").each(function () {
 $(this).replaceWith("<li>" + $(this).html() + "</li>");
  });
```